# VORTAC symbol over KMOT airport - is the small dot the center?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, vor

I am looking at KMOT and I see a little dot over the airport symbol, is that the center of the VORTAC?

[image]

Comment: When you say "over" the airport symbol, do you mean the dot inside the blue circle and between the west ends of the runways, or the dot inside the star above the blue circle?

Comment: Hello Pondlife, I mean the dot inside the airport, I added picture for clarification.

Comment: Yes.  That small dot is the approx.  location of the VOR/VOR-DME/VORTAC on an airfield, should the airfield be so equipped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dot in the center of the star means that there is a rotating beacon available on the airport from sunset to sunrise.

See the [FAA Aeronautical Chart Users Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/media/Chart_Users_Guide_12thEd.pdf) Page 8.

[image]

The actual center of the VORTAC is the small dot between the runways:

[image]

Which you can find the description of in the chart users guide on page 8 as well:

[image]

Comment: It says the star represents the rotating beacon, I am wondering about the small dot, I want to know where to gauge the center for the VORTAC

Comment: @Jeff See the edit